# How can we read a file from Assets a file dir which is made by me in Android application?

Tags: android

How can I read a file from Assets a file dir which is made by me in Android application?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
            try {

               InputStream in = getAssets().open("EULA.txt");

               if (in != null)
               {
                    in = getAssets().open("EULA.txt");
                    int siz = in.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[siz];
                    in.read(buffer);
                    result = new String(buffer);
                    in.close();
                }

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,this i can do it ,but while i create a file dir and put one file in it ,i can not read this file .

Comment: You can do like this
InputStream in = getAssets().open("YourFolder/EULA.txt");

Answer (score 1):

try using like this

```
InputStream myInput = this.getAssets().open("your_dir/yourfilename");
```

Comment: let me have a try ,Thanks a lot

Comment: if it is solved your problem then accept the answer, then only others will use this answer.